# Get annotated methods from gradle plugin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a gradle plugin for android projects in kotlin and I need to scan the project source files in order to get all tests' names. I have implemented a directory scanner and I got an `Arraylist<File>` with all test classes.

I tried to apply reflection to this files but I got always a no class found exception. I suppose that the gradle plug in is trying to find the class inside the same gradle plugin the project instead of the Android project where the plugin is used.

Is there any way to scan each File object in my ArrayList and get all methods with the annotation `@test`?

Comment: Why do you need to find these tests instead of using `gradle test` or these configurations? If your scanner finds your source files, you'd have to analyse the text file yourself. If you have a list of class files, you'd have to add these to the classpath to use them.

Comment: I need all tests names in order to create a tests plan in order to run each test following my own test plan applying my own sharing rules

Comment: Would you mind adding relevant code to your question?

Comment: What files are in the mentioned `ArrayList<File>`? Source files or class files? How did you *apply reflection* to these files? Why do you want to access the (source or class) file contents via a Gradle plugin? If the files are accessed via Gradle, during or after which task of Gradle should the files be accessed? During compile (maybe use an annotation processor) or during runtime (of tests)?

Comment: @lu.koerfer in my `ArrayList<Files>` are the tests' source files. I want to apply reflection to that files in order to discover all the tests inside the project. I want to discover all tests without executing them.

Comment: You cannot apply reflection to source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you have is a list of all the **source** files in your project, you'll need to iterate over them, opening each in turn and reading them (as text) to find any method name that follows an `@Test` annotation.

Depending on how strong your coding standards are, and how well they are followed, that might be almost trivial or quite hard.  In our code base you could simply look for lines matching `^\s+@Test` and then match the next line against `^\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+(\w+)\(` to get the method name.  (Or tokenize it, if you prefer.)  That's pretty much your simplest possible case; if your code base uses `@Ignore` to disable tests, or someone wraps a test in a multi-line comment block (`/* ...  */`), or if there can be strange formatting, missing access modifiers, etc. then your job will be harder.

Oh, and I wouldn't bother searching here for how to ignore comments in code - most of the first hits do it wrong.  Errors include assuming that multi-line comments start at the beginning of a line (there is no leading content on a line that matches a multi-line comment start) and end at the end of a line; that if a line contains a multi-line comment start it does not *also* need to be checked for a single-line comment (which may comment out the multi-line comment start, depending on order), and other problems.

Comment: This could be a good generic solution. In my particular problem, due to I'm trying to find all the instrumentationTests I found that using this library I'm able to get all classes and test names https://github.com/linkedin/dex-test-parser